# How to transfer files from Google play bucket to AWS bucket?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage

Is there any way to transfer files from Google bucket to AWS S3 bucket.

Scenarios is...
I am the owner for **AWS S3 bucket**, but Google bucket is not owned by me.

It belongs to Google Play. I just have access to that Google bucket.

On **Google Play Bucket** all my android apps reports is stored. 
I have to **synchronize files between both bucket** every week.

I tried with **"Transfer"** option on **Google Cloud Storage** (Google Cloud Platform Console), 
but that allows to transfer files from another provider bucket to Google bucket.

Google API's won't help here because I am not the ower of the google bucket.
So cannot get API access for the bucket.

I went through this question on stack overflow, but didn't help 
[How to move files in Google Cloud Storage from one bucket to another bucket by Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25972482/how-to-move-files-in-google-cloud-storage-from-one-bucket-to-another-bucket-by-p)

Solution that allows me for this transfer in PHP will be awesome for me.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

Some other option which helps to automate process will also be great.

Comment: Can you run a CP command on that Google bucket?

Comment: Yes, if you mean cp (copy) command on gsutil tool

Comment: Can you start a EC2 micro instance in your AWS (You can use the free tier too here)?