# How to move blob from one bucket to another bucket in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am using the python code here to move one object from one bucket to another one:
So would like to do a same function as below using command line but in python version:

`gsutil mv gs://bucket_name_1/subfolder1/session1 gs://bucket_name_2/subfolder1/session1`

The variable I give to call the function is:

```
move_blob('gs://bucket_name_1', 'subfolder1/session1', 'gs://bucket_name_2', 'subfolder1/session1')
```

But it is giving the 404 error, do we know what should be the correct variables to put in the function?

```
from google.cloud import storage

def move_blob(bucket_name, blob_name, destination_bucket_name, destination_blob_name,):
    """Moves a blob from one bucket to another with a new name."""
    # The ID of your GCS bucket
    # bucket_name = "your-bucket-name"
    # The ID of your GCS object
    # blob_name = "your-object-name"
    # The ID of the bucket to move the object to
    # destination_bucket_name = "destination-bucket-name"
    # The ID of your new GCS object (optional)
    # destination_blob_name = "destination-object-name"

    storage_client = storage.Client()

    source_bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    source_blob = source_bucket.blob(blob_name)
    destination_bucket = storage_client.bucket(destination_bucket_name)

    # Optional: set a generation-match precondition to avoid potential race conditions
    # and data corruptions. The request is aborted if the object's
    # generation number does not match your precondition. For a destination
    # object that does not yet exist, set the if_generation_match precondition to 0.
    # If the destination object already exists in your bucket, set instead a
    # generation-match precondition using its generation number.
    # There is also an `if_source_generation_match` parameter, which is not used in this example.
    destination_generation_match_precondition = 0

    blob_copy = source_bucket.copy_blob(
        source_blob, destination_bucket, destination_blob_name, if_generation_match=destination_generation_match_precondition,
    )
    source_bucket.delete_blob(blob_name)

    print(
        "Blob {} in bucket {} moved to blob {} in bucket {}.".format(
            source_blob.name,
            source_bucket.name,
            blob_copy.name,
            destination_bucket.name,
        )
    )
```

Comment: Do you need the generation match condition? Did you try without it?

Comment: can you try to call the function with just the name of the bucket not the full URI(`gs://`)

Comment: Thank you! Tried to remove the ```gs:// ``` and it do work if I specify a single file name. but the session1 in the example path is a folder so would like to copy all files within the folder to another bucket, do we know if we can still use above python function to achieve that ?

Comment: @YihanBao I have provided an answer below.please check and let me know if the below suggestions were helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example you are calling the function with URI(`gs://`),it expects the name of the bucket not the full URL (`gs://`)

So you should call the function like this

```
move_blob('bucket_name_1', 'subfolder1/session1', bucket_name_2', 'subfolder1/session1')
```

And yes, you can use this function to move all files within a folder to another bucket.However, keep in mind that Google Cloud Storage operates with a flat namespace, which means that folders don't actually exist within Cloud Storage. If you create an object named `folder1/file.txt` in the bucket `your-bucket`, the path to the object is `your-bucket/folder1/file.txt`, but there is no folder named `folder1`; instead, the string `folder1` is part of the object's name.
You can refer to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/folders)

You can also check the below examples

[Move files between GCP Buckets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72492364/python-move-files-between-gcp-buckets)

[How to move files in Google Cloud Storage from one bucket to another bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25972482/how-to-move-files-in-google-cloud-storage-from-one-bucket-to-another-bucket-by-p)

Comment: Thank you! I will get the list of objects first and call above function with a loop