# AttributeError: 'Blob' object has no attribute 'copy_to' in Google Cloud Function using python for transfering file from one bucket to another bucket

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, cloudevents

I am trying to transfer a file from one bucket to another bucket using Python code in Google Cloud Function but I am getting this error "AttributeError: 'Blob' object has no attribute 'copy_to'".
These are some additional details about the process.
source_bucket : gcf-v2-uploads-632430838198-us-east1
target_bucket : ca-app-corp-finance-dev-444
target_path : gs://ca-app-corp-finance-dev-444/process/fin_essbase/data/incoming/essbase/
filename : key.ppk

I tried below code

```
from google.cloud import storage

def transfer_file(data, context):

source_bucket_name = "gcf-v2-uploads-632430838198-us-east1"

destination_bucket_name = "ca-app-corp-finance-dev-444"

target_path = "process/fin_essbase/data/incoming/essbase/"

filename = "key.ppk"


storage_client = storage.Client()

source_bucket = storage_client.bucket(source_bucket_name)

destination_bucket = storage_client.bucket(destination_bucket_name)



source_blob = source_bucket.blob(filename)

destination_blob = destination_bucket.blob(target_path + filename)



source_blob.copy_to(destination_blob)

source_blob.delete()



print(f"File {filename} transferred successfully.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error "AttributeError: 'Blob' object doesn't have the 'copy_to' attribute." suggests that the `copy_to` method isn't available for the `Blob` object you're using from the Google Cloud Storage library version you have. The `copy_to` method isn't a regular feature for the `Blob` class in Google Cloud Storage.

To copy a file from one storage bucket to another, you should use the `copy_blob` method provided by the `Bucket` class. Here's how you can adjust your code to make it work:

```
    source_blob = source_bucket.blob(filename)
    destination_blob = destination_bucket.blob(target_path + filename)

    new_blob = source_bucket.copy_blob(source_blob, destination_bucket, destination_blob)
    source_blob.delete()

    print(f"The file {filename} has been successfully transferred.")
```

In this piece of code, the `copy_blob` method from the source bucket is used to copy the file to the destination bucket. After that, the original file is removed from the source bucket.

For more information, you can check these references:

- [Copying an object between buckets:](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/samples/storage-copy-file)
- [Moving files in Google Cloud Storage between buckets using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25972482/how-to-move-files-in-google-cloud-storage-from-one-bucket-to-another-bucket-by-p)

Comment: I am getting this error.

File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/_helpers/__init__.py", line 352, in _bytes_to_unicode raise ValueError("%r could not be converted to unicode" % (value,)) ValueError: <Blob: ca-app-corp-finance-dev-444, process/fin_essbase/data/incoming/essbase/key.ppk, None> could not be converted to unicode"

Comment: Try this: print(f"The file {filename} has been successfully transferred to {destination_blob.name}.")

Comment: How can just a print statement create an error? And you are telling to use the same print statement with an addition.Are you are sure?

Comment: The "could not be converted to Unicode" error you're getting isn't likely because of the print statement itself. Instead, it's caused by how the print statement handles the conversion and display of the objects you're providing. My comment says "try" .